# Display custom attribute in invoice pdf magento

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, invoice, pdf

I am having custom attribute called FREE OFFER. now i need to display the values of attribute FREE OFFER in invoice PDF.

[image]

I displayed the attribute in invoice. but when i click print the output PDF is not displaying the attribute.

[image]

```
   this is the output of the pdf its not showing the FREE OFFER attribute
```

anyone can help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To find out how pdf generation works, have a look at these classes:

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` - pdf header & return document
`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract` - parent class of the pdf_invoice class where the functions for rendering and inserting details are defined

To add your attribute to the pdf invoice, you need to rewrite this/these classes:

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default` and/or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Grouped` where product name, sku, qty, etc. are drawed on the pdf